# how to process output of boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

When using boto most of the results that i get are in some form of a list and the contents of this list are Objects.

eg:

if i do

```
def elb_subnets( availability_zone ):
        conn = boto.vpc.connect_to_region('us-west-2',aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key)
        subnet_list = conn.get_all_subnets(filters={"availability-zone":<availability_zone>})
        return subnet_list;


subnet_list = elb_subnets("us-west-2a")

print subnet_list
```

[Subnet:subnet-8b9b31e0]

Now the above is a list which has items of type Subnet.

My problem is, I need to get rid of the part "Subnet:" and only pass subnet-8b9b31e0.

I tried using string operations on the list but get errors saying Subnet object doesn't have str operator modules

So how do i get this done?

This is one use case but i come across this with different modules of boto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subnet object has an id:

```
subnet_ids = [s.id for s in subnet_list]
```

This will give you a list of just the subnet IDs as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, assuming the strings in `subnet_list` always have the format that you showed.

```
subnet_list = ["Subnet:subnet-8b9b31e0","Subnet:subnet-1a1a1a1a", "Subnet:subnet-b2b2b2b2"]
strippedList = [i[7:] for i in subnet_list]
```

Output

```
['subnet-8b9b31e0', 'subnet-1a1a1a1a', 'subnet-b2b2b2b2']
```

Comment: Your suggestion does solve the problem and this technique would come in handy in cases i don't have an attribute to refer to. But in case where i have an attribute of the object its much easier to do it that way. Thanks.